# How can i manually relate pages?

Tags: custom-post-types

I've got a custom post type called Products, which underneath i've got a related products section using a plugin called http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/related-posts-thumbnails/.

I need to be able to create some more post types for example called Accessories and Supplies. I need to be able to relate some accessories to products. How can i make it so when i add an accessory or supply i can say this relates to a certain product and shows in the related products section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible solutions spring to mind, both fairly straightforward:

1. Use a custom taxonomy to create groups then add the accessories and main product to the same group
2. Add an interface that updates the post_parent field to mark items as accessories for a specific product

With either of these approaches you get a fairly easy way to group the products together although the taxonomy approach allows for more flexibility if there are accessories that could be used for multiple products.

Comment: I think custom taxonomy is probably the best way as the plugin for the relates posts uses categories and/or taxonomy. However it needs to be easy for the person i'm making it for. They don't want to have to create a taxonomy every time they add something new. They just want to be able to say, this accessory relates to this product. Is it possible to set it up to work like this?

Comment: If you only need to map an accessory to one product I'd go for the 2nd option. If so I can give you some example code. There's more involved if you go the taxonomy route. That said with a taxonomy you can automatically create the term for each product when the product is created.

Comment: I need to be able to relate an accessory or supply to multiple products. How can i do this using taxonomy?

Comment: Have you used custom taxonomies before?

Comment: No i haven't. When you say you can automatically create the term, is that something custom taxonomies will do already or do i haven't to do something extra to make it do that?

Comment: You have to do some extra legwork to do anything automatic. At the end of the day the time you spend on it is down the clients budget. Don't promise more than a simple taxonomical way to group items if they're not able to pay you enough for the time to do it. I'll update my answer in a bit with an example of the custom taxonomy code and the loop.

Comment: I'm using the taxonomy route to do it. It would be nice though if it was automatic but haven't found a way to do that yet.

Comment: I've found how to automatically create the taxonomy using this. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26389/automatically-create-taxonomy-with-same-name-as-post-title